# Importing html table

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table

I have imported a html table into **R**:

```
require(XML)
u='http://www.ininternet.org/calorie.htm'
tables = readHTMLTable(u)
my.table=tables[[9]]
View(my.table)
```

But now I have problems when I want to analyze the data and apply any function, for example

```
> mean(PROTEINE)
Warning message:
In mean.default(PROTEINE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Please tell me how to import a table so that I could analyze the data properly.

Comment: Look at your object with `str(my.table)` and it will show you the important details of your table quickly and easily.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to calculate the mean of a "factor" type variable:

```
> lapply(my.table, class)
$ALIMENTO
[1] "factor"

$PROTEINE
[1] "factor"

$GRASSI
[1] "factor"

$CARBOIDRATI
[1] "factor"

$CALORIE
[1] "factor"

$COLESTEROLO
[1] "factor"
```

You'll need to converting it to numeric first. Consider:

```
tmp <- as.numeric(as.character(my.table$PROTEINE))
mean(tmp)
## [1] 10.81395
```

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information) for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

They are all factors, change them to character and numeric like this:

```
my.table[,1] <- sapply(my.table[,1], as.character)
my.table[,2:6] <- sapply(my.table[,2:6], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

Or in the original read in, specify `stringsAsFactors=F`. But this isn't perfect because it makes everything a character, so you still need to convert to numeric

```
tables = readHTMLTable(u,stringsAsFactors=F)
my.table[,2:6] <- sapply(my.table[,2:6], as.numeric)
```